# jquery cycle question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

here is a challenging question for a javascript expert and/or someone who has worked with jquery plugin cycle

see my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/atoswchataigner/L8fNS/

question: i can't get the js to display the image for the pager in the nav div (pagerAnchorBuilder in the js)

best viewed in firefox

thank in advance,
Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing `slide.src` with `$('img',$(slide)).get(0).src` fixed the problem, sorry I updated your code by mistake: i'm looking at http://jsfiddle.net/L8fNS/2/ and it works in firefox